# How does the compiler know about the instruction set of my CPU?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, linker, loader

[I've read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831312/compiler-and-linker-difference?rq=1) that

> The compiler converts code written in a human-readable programming language into a
>   machine code representation which is understood by your processor.

How does the compiler know about the instruction set of my CPU?

Any reference to understand job of assembler, linker and loader would be helpful.

Comment: The instruction set is hard-coded into the compiler somewhere.

Comment: @H2CO3: I don't think so, there are 1000s of CPUs in the market.

Comment: @NishithJainMR You certainly haven't heard of modular compilers, have you? The code generator (back-end) must, at some point, have an enormous hash (or so) table with IR mapping to the actual CPU instructions.

Comment: @NishithJainMR Yeah. Intel has shipped thousands of different models of CPUs for the past years. But how are we still able to run Microsoft Entertainment Pack? Same with other CPU manufacturers.

Comment: Through the magic of backwards compatibility and/or upgrading a Pack when migrating to a newer CPU.

Comment: @Vasuki: Check this link
http://lambda.uta.edu/cse5317/notes/node5.html

Comment: Related: [How does an Assembler work at a hardware level?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71719425) - assemblers are just software.

Answer (score 6):

> How does the compiler know about the instruction set of my CPU?

Most compilers only know how emit code for a specific CPU (or a small number of them). Each target CPU requires that someone write a compiler back-end for it, and that task is non-trivial.

GCC supports a large variety of targets, but even GCC is built to emit code for only a few targets. In other words, you can build GCC to emit code for `x86_64` and `i*86` processors, and you can build another copy to emit code for `PowerPC`, but you can't build a single GCC that will produce code for all three.

> Any reference to understand job of assembler, linker and loader

Google search for above terms led me [here](https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~jjohnson/2012-13/fall/cs281/lectures/pdf/cs281_lec04.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

Essentially, each combination of hardware/software requires its own compiler.  So, even though you might write C code in order for it to compile and run on a Windows machine you will still need a compiler that is a different implementation when compared to a C compiler for an Apple machine.

Just to throw in a twist, there are compilers that generate code for hardware that is different from the one they are running on.  A simple example is the Arduino products.  The Arduino IDE runs on a Windows (and others) machine but the code is compiled for an Atmel micro-processor on the Arduino board.  Furthermore, each board style (UNO, etc.) has a different flavor of Atmel mico-processor, which is why in the IDE you have to identify the target of your sketch so that the compiler can make the necessary adjustments to run on the specific hardware(instruction set).

This idea also applies to assemblers and linkers (maybe a little less so).