# How does Visual Studio compile together multiple C++ files?

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, include

I have a simple project in visual studio with `main.cpp`, `Log.cpp`, and `Log.h`.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Log.h"

int main()
{
    Log("Hello World");
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Log.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Log.h"

void Log(std::string message)
{
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}

void InitLog()
{
    Log("Initialized Logger");
}
```

Log.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

void Log(std::string);
void InitLog();
```

I know that the #include statement copy-pastes all of the included file's code into the file where it's written. My question is that how is it that when I run this, the function Log runs as expected?

We are including the Log.h file from both main.cpp and Log.cpp, but that's just the function declaration. We never include Log.cpp in main.cpp, so how does main.cpp get the function body of Log()?

Comment: Visual Studio the IDE or Visual Studio Code, the editor?

Comment: Visual Studio the IDE

Comment: You just put them all into the same build project and they should get linked automatically.

Comment: While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831312/what-are-the-differences-between-a-compiler-and-a-linker/3831354) is about C, the same basic principle applies: This is one of the roles the linker plays. It resolves external references after translation units have been compiled into object files to turn it all into a single executable.

Comment: From a C++ style perspective this suggests you should have a `Log` class with a constructor (`Log::Log`) and some kind of `log(const std::string& message)` function. Note the use of `const` reference. This saves copying the value which can get expensive, but is almost always wasteful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as the process of *linking*. The compiler needs to know the return types and signatures of the functions in the `Log` class (which is why you include the header), but it wont throw errors if it doesn't find the function definitions. When it compiles the cpp files into object code files, it basically leaves "holes" where the function definitions are supposed to go. Then the linker is used to link those object files together into one executable.

The compiler does, however, need to know the data members of your class because those determine how much memory an object occupies, which is necessary for object creation. Again, these are included in the class definition in the header file included in main.