# How does my compiler know what printf() does?

Tags: c, printf, header-files, standard-library

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I'm new to this and trying to understand things.

Let's say I want to write a simple "Hello World" program:

```
// hello.c
int main() {
    printf("%s\n", "Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't compile because my compiler doesn't know what "printf" is (I'm using gcc on Ubuntu). So I `#include <stdio.h>` and now I can compile it and it works as expected. But why? stdio.h is only a header file containing the declaration of "printf". When I include it, gcc knows what "printf" **is** and how to call it, but how does it know what "printf" actually **does?**

I assume that the actual implementation of printf and the other functions declared in stdio.h is somewhere in some precompiled object file, let's call it stdio.o (even though I didn't find such a file in any directory). Why don't I have to include that object file for gcc to know the actual implementation of printf? I mean, why don't I have to do something like this:

`gcc hello.c stdio.o -o hello`

When I write an object file myself, I need to explicitly include the object file:

```
// main.c
#include "myobj.h"
// some code...
```

// in gcc:
`gcc main.c myobj.o -o main`

Why isn't that the case with stdio.h?

Comment: The standard library (containing `printf`'s implementation) is linked by default.

Comment: To ease the process generating a executable from C files, the linker uses a default library (usually libc) which contains the definition of `printf`. That standard library does not only contains things declared in `stdio.h` but in many others. You may use option `-v` with `gcc` to get all commands and options used behind the scene.

Comment: Try compiling with the option `-nodefaultlibs` and you'll get exactly the error you expect about printf being missing.  The necessary library, libc, is added automatically unless certain options are used to disable it.

Comment: @GSerg It does, thank you. Looks like I should have searched for "definition" instead of "implementation" and whatever wrong term I looked for. Sorry and thank you

Comment: Apart from including `printf()` as part of the standard library, GCC also knows what `printf()` is supposed to do because it is a standard function. This allows it to warn about apparently wrong usage such as `printf("%d\n", "Hello");`. This is indeed an example of modern times luxury :-)

Comment: It helps to understand [the difference between compiler and linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831312/what-are-the-differences-between-a-compiler-and-a-linker).

Comment: @moped Your code is correct, no worries :-). I just gave an example of the wonders of modern day compilers which are much appreciated by those of us who have been around when it was common to have programs behaving strange because of mismatch in `printf` format string and parameters. Such warnings cannot be based on the generic declaration in the header file, but has to be built into the compiler.

Comment: It doesn't know what it does. All it knows is that the function exists, with such-and-such a calling sequence and such-and-such a return type. As long as you call it correctly the compiler doesn't care what it does.

Comment: @user207421 That is true for the information the compiler gets from the header file, but as I have tried to say above, the compiler can provide additional checks for standard functions where the compiler has built-in knowledge of the function behavior. Such as it is the case with GCC and `printf`.